# How to still play the video after pausing once but after control is being enabled, the addeventlistener is not working at all?

Tags: javascript, html

I am a beginner in JavaScript, I want to play and pause the video whenever the user clicks the video element, but when in my code once user clicks again the video element the video gets paused and control gets enabled but when again user clicks the paused video after the controls being enabled the `addEventListener()` is not working at all it seems, can anyone please tell why this is happening, I saw that after I remove line  `videoelement.controls = true;` then all works fine, but I want to know why this is happening and is there any way that with controls enabled it works fine enough

```js
let videoelement = document.querySelector('.videos')
videoelement.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    console.log(videoelement.paused)
    if (videoelement.paused) {
        console.log("pause hai ")
        videoelement.play();
        videoelement.controls = null;
        videoelement.firstChild.nodeValue = 'Play';
    } else {
        console.log("play ho gya")
        videoelement.pause();
        videoelement.controls = true;
        videoelement.firstChild.nodeValue = 'Pause';
    }
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

```css
body
{
    background-color: blueviolet
}
.videos
{
    width: 50%;
    margin:10% 20%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Video Player</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="videplayercss.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="videoplayer">
    <video src="anyvideo.mp4" autoplay class="videos"> </video>
  </div>
  <script src="videoplayerjs.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: "_If the user agent exposes a user interface to the user ..., then the user agent __should suppress any user interaction events__ ..._" Chapter 4 in [the standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#user-interface).

Comment: you mean to say that I should not include the line ` videoelement.controls = true;`

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what the standard says.

Comment: ok ....I thought there would some way to exercise the control over play and pause even when the controls are enabled ...by clicking on the video element anywhere ... I asked this even addeventlistener is also not working after that